# Extract elements from .npy file, convert them to PyTorch tensors

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, deserialization, pytorch

I read a .npy file that contains just the labels for images. The labels are stored in dictionary format. I need to convert this to an array of Tensors. But I'm unable to extract elements one of the other from the object the file returns, which is numpy.ndarray type.

```
import numpy as np
data = np.load('/content/drive/My Drive/targets.npy')
print(data.item())


{0: array(5), 1: array(0), 2: array(4), 3: array(1), 4: array(9), 5: array(2), 6: array(1), 7: array(3)}

print(data[()].values())

dict_values([array(5), array(0), array(4), array(1), array(9), array(2), array(1), array(3)])
```

I would like to create an array of tensors instead.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below worked for me, with guidance by @kmario23

```
import numpy as np
data = np.load('/content/drive/My Drive/targets.npy')
print(data.item())

{0: array(5), 1: array(0), 2: array(4), 3: array(1), 4: array(9), 5: array(2), 6: array(1), 7: array(3)}
# data is a 0-d numpy.ndarray that contains a dictionary. 

print(list(data[()].values()))

[array(5),
 array(0),
 array(4),
 array(1),
 array(9),
 array(2),
 array(1),
 array(3),
 array(1),
 array(4),
 array(3)]

# torch.Tensor(5) gives tensor([2.0581e-35, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00])
# torch.tensor(5) gives 5
# unsure of why the difference exists..

Labels = torch.stack([torch.tensor(i) for i in list_of_labels_array_form])

print(Labels)

tensor([5, 0, 4,  ..., 2, 5, 0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `data` is a dict:

```
In [59]: dct = {0: np.array([5]), 1: np.array([0]), 2: np.array([4]), 
                3: np.array([1]), 4: np.array([9]), 5: np.array([2]), 
                6: np.array([1]), 7: np.array([3])}
```

You can use `numpy.concatenate()` wrapped in `torch.tensor()` to get a tensor out of it:

```
In [63]: torch.tensor(np.concatenate(list(dct.values())))
Out[63]: tensor([5, 0, 4, 1, 9, 2, 1, 3])
```

---

Additionally, if you want both keys and values to be stacked in a single 2D tensor, then use `torch.cat()`

```
# tensor with just keys
In [86]: tk = torch.tensor(list(dct.keys()))
In [87]: tk
Out[87]: tensor([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])

# tensor with just values
In [88]: tv = torch.tensor(np.concatenate(list(dct.values())))
In [89]: tv
Out[89]: tensor([5, 0, 4, 1, 9, 2, 1, 3])

# horizontally stack them into a single 2D tensor
In [85]: torch.cat((tk[:, None], tv[:, None]), dim=1)
Out[85]: 
tensor([[0, 5],
        [1, 0],
        [2, 4],
        [3, 1],
        [4, 9],
        [5, 2],
        [6, 1],
        [7, 3]])
```

---

After a series of comments, I have now understood your problem and here is the way to solve it:

```
In [48]: data_item = {0: np.array(5), 1: np.array(0), 2: np.array(4), 
                      3: np.array(1), 4: np.array(9), 5: np.array(2),
                      6: np.array(1), 7: np.array(3)}

# convert keys to an 1D tensor
In [53]: tk = torch.tensor(list(data_item.keys()))

In [54]: tk
Out[54]: tensor([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

Since you have the values as arrays of 0D (i.e. scalars), we need to extract the elements from them. For this, we can use `lambda` function alongside `map`, whose job is to apply the lambda function on the iterable (here: `data_item.values()`) and give us the elements. These can be passed to `torch.tensor` to get the desired 1D tensor.

```
# convert values to an 1D tensor
In [57]: tv = torch.tensor(list(map(lambda a: a.item(), data_item.values())))

In [58]: tv
Out[58]: tensor([5, 0, 4, 1, 9, 2, 1, 3])

# horizontally stack them into a single 2D tensor, if needed
In [85]: torch.cat((tk[:, None], tv[:, None]), dim=1)
Out[85]: 
tensor([[0, 5],
        [1, 0],
        [2, 4],
        [3, 1],
        [4, 9],
        [5, 2],
        [6, 1],
        [7, 3]])
```

Comment: The problem is that, it is not a dictionary. data.values() gives this: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: its a dictionary stored as a single element in the ndarray

Comment: @aneeshaasc could you please give a simple example of how `data` looks like?

Comment: {0: array(5), 1: array(0), 2: array(4), 3: array(1), 4: array(9), 5: array(2), 6: array(1), 7: array(3)}

Comment: don't worry, i think i found a way .

Comment: for i in data[()].values():
  print(i)

Comment: this lets me extract elements from the dictionary contained in the 0 -d array

Comment: I now need to figure out how to make these list of numbers a list of stacked tensors

Comment: Or you can use: `list(map(lambda a: a.item(), data.values()))`. So, you wish to have a 2D tensor or different 1D tensors for keys and values?

Comment: I just need to convert these dict_values to tensors